# Merge 2 dataset python (Closed)

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have an issue merging 2 CSV into a new dataset. So far, I have merged them.
Let's say I have csv1 and csv2. I created a 'df' from csv1 and I merged csv2 with a specific column. But here is my problem:

**I need to create a new column in df (e.g. 'new_foo', because both CSV has the same column name, but different data, so it's not possible to merge the 2 foo columns**) and relate the two columns from ***merged csv2 column X***. This is because in csv1 the common column is *X*.

Current Input:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(csv1)
csv2_df = pd.read_csv(csv2)
csv2_column_x=csv2_df['x']
new_foo=csv2_df['foo']
df['new_foo']
df = df.merge(csv2_column_x, how="outer").merge(new_foo, how="outer")
```

Current Output:

| X | Y | foo | new_foo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'bla1' | 'qwer' | 12 |
| 1 | 'bla2' | 'aswd' | 34 |
| 1 | 'bla3' | 'asdf' |  |
| 2 | 'bla4' | 'azer' |  |

Desired Output:

| X | Y | foo | new_foo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'bla1' | 'qwer' | 12 |
| 1 | 'bla2' | 'aswd' | 12 |
| 1 | 'bla3' | 'asdf' | 12 |
| 2 | 'bla4' | 'azer' | 34 |

This is my csv1:

| X | Y | foo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'bla1' | 'qwer' |
| 1 | 'bla2' | 'aswd' |
| 1 | 'bla3' | 'asdf' |
| 2 | 'bla4' | 'azer' |

This is my csv2:

| X | foo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 34 |

NOTE: The CSV files have different numbers of rows.

Comment: I don't see how you can possibly get your "current output" from the input + code that you have shown.  Where are `45` and `67` coming from?

Comment: Because I have more rows than that, let me edit, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pandas join method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the dataframes on column `X`.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

csv1_df = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
csv2_df = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv")
merged = csv1_df.join(csv2_df.set_index('X'), on='X', lsuffix='_caller', rsuffix='_other')
print(merged)
```

**Output:**

```
   X       Y foo_caller  foo_other
0  1  'bla1'     'qwer'         12
1  1  'bla2'     'aswd'         12
2  1  'bla3'     'asdf'         12
3  2  'bla4'     'azer'         34
```

`csv1.csv`:

```
X,Y,foo
1,'bla1','qwer'
1,'bla2','aswd'
1,'bla3','asdf'
2,'bla4','azer'
```

`csv2.csv`:

```
X,foo
1,12
2,34
```

**References:**

- [Pandas documentation on join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

Answer (score 0):

I finally did what Arsho told me and it's working perfectly. Instead of using the .merge() method, I used the .join() method to concatenate the CSV as I desired.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).